# Running a package as a script: executing __main__.py without importing __init__.py

Tags: python, package

My package directory is as follow:

```
foo/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
setup.py
```

If that matters, I installed it using setuptools.

Now, if I have a Python code with the line `import foo`, then `__init__.py` is executed and `__main__.py` is not executed. This is fine.

But if I run the command `python -m foo`, both `__init__.py` and `__main__.py` are executed. I would like `__main__.py` to be executed without `__init__.py`.

**How can I achieve that?**

I have the desired behavior if I run `python foo` when `foo` is in my working directory. However, this does not work anymore when I run the command from some other directory (I have the error `No such file or directory`, as expected).

---

The motivation behind that is that `foo` is a library that relies on some shared C library (call it `c_foo`). You cannot import `foo` if `c_foo` doesn't exist on your system (it throws an exception). I do not want to install automatically `c_foo` with setup.py since it may be shared or the user may want to have a custom installation. However, I want to embed an installation script in `foo` to help the user to install `c_foo` if needed. So I would like `python -m foo` to be the entry point of the installation script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. `__init__` is the *core* of the package and will **always** be imported for anything from the package.

You'll have to move the code from `__main__.py` to live outside the package, or move the code you don't want executed from `__init__.py` to another module.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way in `__init__.py` to know if `foo` is imported or executed as a script? The classical test `__name__ == '__main__'` does not work here since `__name__` is always `'foo'`.

Comment: @TomCornebize: due to how the `-m` switch is implemented, `sys.argv[0] == '-c'` will be true when `__init__.py` is imported to execute the package as a script. That *is* a little fragile, future Python versions may alter how `-m` is implemented.